# How to play strange Emadd9 and Am6 chords in this song?

Tags: chords, classical-guitar

I'm trying to play this song: https://musescore.com/user/26991134/scores/5554268

I have downloaded, pasted into a new score sheet in musescore and added a Guitar Tab Starve.
But, for the two first chords: Emadd9 and Am6, the auto generated Tab indications are very strange:

> **Emadd9:** String1 - Fret 2, Open String2, Open String3, String6 - Fret3

How can I play this without playing strings 4th and 5th?

> **Am6:** String1 - Fret 2, String2 - Fret 1, String3 - Fret 2, Open String 5

How can I play this without playing string 4th?

**NOTE:** I have been doing some research and it seems like in this tab the bass notes are 'second voice' notes. That's means that are supposed to play with another instrument like a piano or a bass.

Thank you.

[image: Guitar Tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have used the *classical-guitar* tag**

This is a classical guitar piece. Therefore you do not strike all the strings as you would with a pick/plectrum. You use the right hand fingertips (or fingernails) to pluck only the strings that you need.

The right-hand fingers are labelled as pima**

Notice that you can pluck all the strings together or, in this case, one at a time in quick succession.

There are lots of tutorials online if you search for ***pima guitar***, e.g.

---

**
P = pulgar (thumb)
I = indice (index finger)
M = medio (middle finger)
A = anular (ring finger)

Comment: Thank you very much. Not sure if this technique it's applicable here, but it's a good technique to learn! Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is meant to be played finger style, like on classical guitar.
Then the bass would be played with the thumb and the top notes with fingers 1, 2, and 3, also called, i, m, a, of the plucking hand.

If you are using a pick you might want to use a hybrid technique where you use the 2, 3, ad 4 fingers of the plucking hand to grab the top notes and the pick to act as a thumb.

Yet another option, if the song is not too fast, is to play the bass note first then the top chord.  The wavy line would indicate they want the chord arpeggiated, meaning to have the notes played with a slight separation in time, like on a harp.

Comment: Not exactly. The three notes are arpeggiated, but the bass note needs to be played at  the same time as the arpeggio starts - on the 3rd string. So bass and 3rd string together. The squiggly line says so. And what's the treble clef sign doing on TAB..?

Comment: I agree but I'm giving other options for he OP to try if they are hell bent on using a pick only.  It will require some reinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not supposed to strum the chord, you just pluck those strings one by one/in a fingerstyle picking pattern.